# How to parse string and get some information out of whole string in python

Tags: python, python-2.7, python-3.x, nltk

I am trying to draw a tree diagram for each family. I have a information about family is like that :

> His mother is working at google. He has two sisters, one is working at
>   hospital and another one is studying.

How I can parse a string to get this final output in dict like this.

> {'mother' : [google], 'sister' : [hospital, studying] }

Need suggestions!!

Comment: FYI, this isn't an easy problem. http://www.nltk.org/

Comment: @leaf : I new to this. I don't know why my questions always get down voted. I never ask them to give me code. Some people ask me that what kind of output you want so I always add my expected output. I just want suggestions and nothing else.

Comment: Look at this: http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: @Flummox :  Thank you.  I will take care. I will learn NLTK and will post answer. stay tuned :-)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Short answer, you are not going to be able to do so.

Longer answer, buckle up Raj, for you will have to learn [Natural Language Processing](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Natural_language_processing) to be able to do what you want. And that, my unknown internet stranger, is very hard to do.

Good luck!

*edit: [Natural language Programming](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Natural_language_programming) is fun too.*

*edit2 thanks @ [Jordan McQueen](https://stackoverflow.com/users/5875532/jordan-mcqueen) & [juanpa.arrivillaga](https://stackoverflow.com/users/5014455/juanpa-arrivillaga) for making this a better answer*

Comment: I believe you mean natural language *[processing](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Natural_language_processing)*.

Comment: ya I mean to natural language processing